# How do you install minecraft minigames?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I install the *Tetris Escape* map for Minecraft 1.7.2. I've tried almost everything but it wont download. Can I have some advice.

Comment: Are you asking how to download a map from a website or are you asking how to play it? If you are asking how to download it, what site?

Comment: By searching for "Tetris Escape Minecraft" I found [this](http://www.planetminecraft.com/project/172-mini-game-make-it-out-alive/) which you should be able to download with the "Minecraft World Save" link (use CTRL+F in your browser to search for the text if you have trouble finding it)

Answer (score 2):

Simply extract the folder inside the zip file into the %APPDATA%.minecraft\saves folder. When you start Minecraft and press Singleplayer, you should find the map there. Enjoy!